# Is there any uniqe id provided by WorkLight?

Tags: java, javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to construct a request to web service from WorkLight server with a unique id for EACH request.

So, the question. Is there any provided Class(Java) or function(JS) from WorkLight or I have to implement it myself.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a unique id using JavaScript, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6248722/186909). The relevant bit:

```
function generateUIDNotMoreThan1million() {
   return ("0000" + (Math.random()*Math.pow(36,4) << 0).toString(36)).substr(-4)
}
```

There's more info. inside the original answer, you should be able to modify it to fit your needs if 4 chars is too small. Sample usage:

```
generateUIDNotMoreThan1million()
"z38b"
generateUIDNotMoreThan1million()
"4szu"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but I'm still not accept your answer to wait for what I exactly want. :)

Comment: There is not a Worklight-provided unique identifier AFAIK. Use cnandreu's suggestion.